# How to store the metadata present in different folder collectively, so that it can be queried later on?

Tags: python, metadata

- I have lots of folder starting with the same initial sequence.
- Each folder contains a metadata file.
- In each metadata file we have attribute and value pair.
- I want to query all folder that have contains specific set of attribute value pair (ie. The user will select an attribute and enter
  the value it wants to search).

I have used python so far to store all these folder in one place. Can this be done using python? Any suggestion or resource which can help me in this direction is appreciated. If it can be done in any other way than please tell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an include a small sample: Some folders, some files in them, your Python code.

Comment: Like `grep -l searched_attr=searched_value initial_sequence_*/metadata` ?